# Maven archetype generate pull newer or latest templates

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

We can use maven to generate project templates using `mvn archetype:generate` then pick an archetype number. If say I pick number 1977 `1977: remote -> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-sample-tomcat-archetype (Spring Boot Tomcat Sample)`. Maven will generate the java project and so on.

When I check the `pom.xml` file I see

```
<parent>
        <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

It seems that the `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `1.0.2.RELEASE` is from April 2014. Quite old now that it's 2019.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent

My maven version is: `apache-maven-3.5.4`.

How do we get a newer template/archetype from maven?

Comment: What does the spring boot web page say about the recommended archetype?

Comment: @JFMeier I cannot find a good reference. This ones also still points to 2014 version: https://repo.spring.io/release/archetype-catalog.xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find a more recent sample on github:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat

However, I think that springboot has stopped using archetypes in favor of [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/).

There you would pick whatever version you want and add a `Web` dependency to have the Tomcat and MVC framework starter included.

Comment: You beat me to it! Spring Initializr is the way to go, and maven central (the reference) does not provide more recent version of the archetype : https://search.maven.org/search?q=spring-boot-sample-tomcat-archetype